# Entity Framework Plus - Using IncludeFilter and Include

Tags: entity-framework-plus

I read the documentation and I see that the limitation when using IncludeFilter is that I can't combine it with EF Include.  Has anyone came into this situation where they used IncludeFilter but needed to load a navigation property that originally would have been handled by EF Include?  What's the best way to load the additional navigation property?

https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently impossible to combine `IncludeFilter` and `Include`. That's a limitation of our library.

However, you can use `IncludeFilter` without a filter. So to make it work, you just need to replace ALL include by `IncludeFilter` no matter if there is a filter or not.

Comment: I thought the library got updated to latest version 1.8.25 but it looked like the project was still on version 1.2.5.  After confirming that the update was successful I tried the IncludeFilter again and this time I got the expected result.

Comment: Is it possible to filter non-IQueryable like a reference type. For example; I want to have Address Entity on Customer only if its Active property set to True? I tried this: "context.Filter<Address>(a=> a.Where(b=>b.Active))". It does not apply while using IncludeFilter(a=>a.Address)

Comment: Is this still a limitation on 2021?